# If I refresh my website, images with slideshow effects disappear

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, fade

Images disappear if I refresh the website. But if I click the sideshow arrow, it reappears. The main Problem is If I refresh, images are missing and only sideshow arrows are shown if I click either one of the arrows, the images reapper and work well. is there any way to fix it?
I will provide codes and screenshot of my website.
[No Images if I refresh and only arrows are shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A96WE.png)[Images must shown like this as default.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WKrJ.jpg)

```
    let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Above codes are JavaScript.

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
                <div class="mySlides fade">
                  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
                  <img src="images/pink_tulip_rs.jpeg" style="width:100%">
                  <div class="text-block">
                    <h4>Covid-19 Update</h4>
                    <p>Walk-in trade deferred, Web Order only!</p>
                    <a href="announcement.html">See announcement</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="mySlides fade">
                  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                  <img src="images/tulip_white_bg_rs.jpeg" style="width:100%">
                  <div class="text-block">
                    <h4>Discount - 30% off</h4>
                    <p>From March, 13, 2020</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="mySlides fade">
                  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                  <img src="images/colorful_flower.jpeg" style="width:100%">
                  <div class="text-block">
                    <h4>New Arrivals!</h4>
                    <a href="announcement.html">See Specials</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
                
                </div>
                <br>
                
                <div style="text-align:center">
                  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
                  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
                  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
            </div>
```

Comment: I think you need to wait for the DOMContentLoaded event before calling showSlides the first time : `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    showSlides(slideIndex);})`

Comment: @Lk77 where should I put that?

Comment: well in your js at the begining, after let slideIndex = 0;